# PL/SQL VARCHAR2 variables' sizes in memory

Tags: oracle, plsql

When declaring a new VARCHAR2 variable in PL/SQL, for instanceL

```
lv_myVar    VARCHAR2(255);
```

Is there any 'penalty' if I use 256 vs 255 or 1024 vs 1023? Are the variables allocate the exact number of bytes in memory, or is there rather some binary multiplication which uses multiples of twos to store the data in RAM?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the below threads with some testing done on varchar collections and other background details. But the general idea is if your max length of the string is 10 better store it in VARCHAR2(10) rather than VARCHAR2(32767).

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536579800346614104

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=why-multiple-versions-what-would-be-the-cause-of-bind-mismatch